# Using gson to parse JSON file, something odd is going on

Tags: java, gson

Using [google's json parser](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), i test file's content to see if it can be parsed:

```
...
FileReader fullPathToAndNameOfFile = new FileReader(file);
isJson(fullPathToAndNameOfFile);
...

private static boolean isJson(FileReader f) {

    try {
        parser.parse(f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problem is .. the following format validates without errors:

```
a:12
b:27
c:Mike
```

Which, of course is not a valid JSON format.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the poblem with below code.

```
private static boolean isJson(FileReader f) {
try{
     JsonElement json = new JsonParser().parse(f);
   }
catch (Exception e) {
     return false;
   }
return true;
}
```

`Inside main`

```
parser p = new parser();
String file = "C:\\Users\\RanRag\\test.txt";
FileReader fullPathToAndNameOfFile = new FileReader(file);

if(p.isJson(fullPathToAndNameOfFile))
   System.out.println("valid");
else
   System.out.println("invalid");
```

Output for your given file contents = `invalid`.

If I change the file content to [valid json](http://jsonlint.com/). For eg:

```
{ "name": "Simon" }
```

Output = `valid`

Comment: Very strange .. something odd is going on with my code .. I'll keep looking. Thank you for your time

Comment: @JAM: I tried to make my code exactly like your's still not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Confirmed, I get "MalformedJsonException: Expected EOF at line 1 column 2"

Comment: ok. but I was wondering `MalformedJsonException` is thrown when `when a reader encounters malformed JSON.` but `JsonParser().parse` thorws `JsonParseException` if json is malformed.